# Disable right mouseclick and show tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, contextmenu, mouse, right-click

I try to disable the right mouseclick for images. For this I use the following code.

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', 'img', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This works well.

Now I would like to display a tooltip when I click the right mouse button. I can not do it. Would like to use the bootstrap tooltip.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Tool tips on right-mouse sounds pretty non-standard for a UI. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Where are you stuck???

Comment: you know the event , have the tooltip, you need the coordinates for the current location  of the mouse

Comment: Yes, I want to do that. If I click on a picture with the right mouse button, a tooltip will appear, as at 500px.com ...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this code works fine for me...

```
$('body').on('contextmenu', 'img', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#tooltip').css({
        top: e.pageY + 'px',
        left: e.pageX + 'px'
    }).fadeIn(250);

    $('#tooltip').click(function(){
        $('#tooltip').hide();
    });

    $(document).click(function(){
        $('#tooltip').hide();
    });
});
```

How do I hide the tooltip automatically after a delay of 3 seconds?